# Remove left sidebar shopping cart

Tags: theming, commerce

I know the shopping cart is generated by the view shopping cart form. But how do I remove the shopping cart block on left sidebar of the home page and still maintain the the view on /cart page? I have tried disabling the view entirely, that didn't work as it seems the block is hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you could restrict block from being shown in front page, from block visibility settings. Alternatively, you could also make a custom template for the front page.

Comment: Thanks. I had sorted it by disabling the block entirely. Your suggest is also relevant for cases where the block is needed on specific pages. For me I wanted it out completely.